# Friend Function and Operator Overloading in C++

Tags: c++

I have following code to add two strings `Hi` and `There` using friend function and operator overloading in C++.

```
   #include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
class STRING
{
 char *str;
 public:
     STRING(char *p) { str=p; }
     STRING(STRING& s) { str=s.str; }
     friend STRING operator+(STRING &s1,STRING& s2);
     friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& dout,STRING& s)
     {
      dout<<s.str;
      return dout;
     }
};
STRING operator+(STRING &s1,STRING& s2)
{
 STRING x(s1); int i,j=0;
 for(i=0;x.str[i]!='\0';i++);
 x.str[i]=' ';
 while((x.str[++i]=s2.str[j++])!='\0');
 x.str[i]='\0';
 return x;
}
void main()
{
 clrscr();
 cout<<"\n\n\t\t";
 STRING s1="Hi";     cout<<" String s1: "<<s1<<"\n\n\t\t";
 STRING s2="There"; cout<<" String s2: "<<s2<<"\n\n\t\t";
 STRING s3=s1+s2;     cout<<" S1+S2 is : "<<s3<<"\n\n\t\t";
 getch();
}
```

When I am building solution its not showing any errors but When I am running this program, i am getting following errors in pop up box

```
Unhandled exception at 0x011f1506 in Program 6.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x011f7860.
```

Comment: Apart from zero-containment or ownership of pointers, you're sending read-only data (string-literals) into code thats *writes* to it.

Comment: Maybe you should start by paying attention to the compiler warnings you're undoubtedly getting. Your `operator+` causes undefined behavior for several reasons.

Comment: If he isn't compiling with -Wall or some equivalent option in his compiler, it may not report anything wrong in the operator+ function because there are no syntax errors.  Even with all warnings on it may be that the compiler doesn't recognize that the pointer is read-only since it was passed into the function.

Comment: I tried same program in TURBO C, and its running fine there but not in VS C++ 2010 (Above Program Updated for Turbo C)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing string literals and then modifying them - this is not allowed, you cannot modify "Hi" or "There"

```
x.str[i]=' ';
```

You are also never allocating space for the new bigger string

Comment: I tried same program in TURBO C, and its running fine there but not in VS C++ 2010 (Above Program Updated for Turbo C)

Comment: @AkashSharma May be TURBO C has implemented some magic to overcome your code's flaws automatically ...

Comment: So Is there any patch for this program so that it also run on VS C++

Comment: Running a simple example is not the same as tested.  If you fully test, you will notice your memory management issues.   It is interesting that Turbo C is not protecting string literals and would presumably allow `char * x="RAD"; x[0]='B';` - definately not standard if that works.

Comment: @AkashSharma yeah, its called code that doesn't invoke undefined behavior. Visual C++ isn't the problem; *the code is.*

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum Ok Thanks , May be the sample code I am using is very old and not according to C++ Standard

Comment: @AkashSharma Without understanding memory management - the quickest fix is to replace `char *str` with `std::string str` but that does trivialize things

Comment: @AkashSharma TURBO C/C++ is **ancient**. Seen in some software museums and vintage sites ...